# k-means grouping a file in specific cluster in mapreduce

Tags: java, algorithm, hadoop

I am a newbie to this hadoop platform.

I have gone through the `k-means implementation` 
 [here](https://github.com/thomasjungblut/thomasjungblut-common/tree/master/src/de/jungblut/clustering/mapreduce) 
. But here we are `grouping points`. I need to group different files . So the user must be able to see which `file falls in which group`.

Is there any idea.I searched a lot but not able to find a way. What changes should i make in that code.

```
**UPDATE2**
```

I want to input 100 files.

so which one is better-input all the 100 files within a `directory` or input file1,file2(as `single`).
And how can we `handle` this

Comment: You obviously have to vectorize your files beforehand. If you're dealing with text, you can use tf-idf weighting (also in my repository here https://github.com/thomasjungblut/thomasjungblut-common/blob/master/src/de/jungblut/nlp/mr/TfIdfCalculatorJob.java).

Comment: ok.but it is like indexing...I will update in my question with example - what i am trying to implement :). really running a short time

Comment: Still no idea what you want. Do you want to cluster the text content of your files? And yes you need to translate your files into vectors, thus you need to find a vocabulary that translates to a vector space.

Comment: the only difference to make in your program is http://code.google.com/p/hama-shortest-paths/source/browse/trunk/hama-gsoc/src/de/jungblut/clustering/mapreduce/KMeansClusteringJob.java from line 63 ..there is points right..along with that i need to include index values also. [0:(1,1)] 1 st input data [0:(2,1)] 2 nd input ....now usually we r clustering all the input value right.? but here we should identify the index and do k-means.so for 0 index or say 0 is my file name we hv to do k-means like that u got it? :( for file 1 we have to do k-means

Comment: oh okay sure, you can change the `VectorWritable` class and include the index there. You only have to serialize it in the read/write methods.

Comment: How to do that..I started looking into mapreduce only for few days.so i am not able to update that code.

Comment: I am referring http://code.google.com/p/hama-shortest-paths/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fhama-gsoc%2Fsrc%2Fde%2Fjungblut%2Fclustering%2Fmodel and http://code.google.com/p/hama-shortest-paths/source/browse/trunk/hama-gsoc/src/de/jungblut/clustering/mapreduce/ how to output the the k-means output along with the index.

Comment: Just search for hadoop writable, I guess you will find a lot of tutorials.

Comment: can u update the code for me.I may get wrong.:(

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: ok ok i got

Comment: @ThomasJungblut:I also have another doubt related to same post .only small difference.should i post it as another question or ?

Comment: just send me an email with your doubts :)

Comment: oh sure ..I am not able to view your mail id .can u please tell.:)

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: I emailed my doubts

Comment: Can you please just say once what you want? I see the answer assumes you want to cluster files according to their content, but is that really what you are asking for?

Comment: ys ,i want to cluster files according to their content.any suggessions

Comment: @ThomasJungblut:i mailed my doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is [K-means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)?

There is no doubt , K-means is the simplest cluster algorithm.

**First, k-means is clustering not classification.**

Give you a person's name, you don't know it is a man or woman, but your friend who is a man has the same name, so you think he is a man, this is cluster(Acutually, it is a woman, maybe, we are not sure, we just perfer the most likely answer). 
Give you a man, you are sure he is near you, so you can say he is your neighbour, this is classification.

Clustering files in different files. You should create model(K-means create the model that given a point and falls it to the nearest center point.) and then get the most likely 
answer.

For example,  clustering them by file name. a file called apple maybe in fruit group, a file called mouse maybe in animal group.(All of this is depends on your Points thesaurus)

---

Now, I will show you an Example of how to vectorize it, hmm, must be the simplest.

Assume you have a Point thesaurus. maybe like this

```
Bill Gates  ： IT
iphone  :  IT
basketball :  sports
Michael Jordan : sports
```

Four files

```
file1:  I love iphone very much
file2:  I like play basketball
file3:　Bill Gates is the richest man.
file4:　He is the fans of Michael Jordan.
```

---

We get the **key words**(which is record in point thesaurus) in file.
And then we calc the percent of each file.
now, we get the result

file1: 100% IT, 0%    sport

file2: 0%   IT, 100%  sport

file3: 100% IT, 0%    sport

file4: 0%   IT, 100%  sport

Then we can get two group, IT and sports(Usually, in a file, there are lots of words, so 100% and 0% not exist in real data, don't mind the details)

---

Just have a think, what do this example tell us.

1. A model is something(in this example, it's just a number, most time, it isiz a formula ) which get the connection between data(in this example, this model get the connection between files)
2. what is vectorize? Look carefully, you will get the axis(X is the IT, y is the sport)
3. Why we emphasize vectorize? Now you find one thing! you get axis now, so replace it into K-means, it works now, isn't it?!

Comment: I know what you want to know, but it's a little hard to say in a little words.  This is the knowledge of machine learing. As is said by @Thomas Jungblut , you should vectorize your file by file name. To vectorize them, you need create a model(maybe also need a  Points thesaurus). The hardest thing happened to you is how to create the model, but I can't give you any suggestion as I don't know what's your file name look like, maybe you should tell me more about file name.

Comment: file name can be anything author name or title..I dont know which one is better. any suggesion for that?

Comment: I have show you a example, hope that clear. To know how to cluster something, you'd better learn more about machine learning.

Comment: if possible can u pls give me ur mail id: i will mail u if i hv doubts

Comment: @Karl.Li: WOW . That was a GREAT example!

Comment: i processed my files now my input is "  **1**,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.3,4.0,5.0                               
**2**,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0                                           
**3**,5.0,1.0,3.0,7.0,2.0,4.0  ". 1st files, its data 2 nd file its data.now how will i apply kmeans?